# Android Studio Fragments not loading

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

When loading my program on a device for testing, as I open different fragments using the bottom navigation nothing happens what so ever. If you need me to add more code please say so. I've posted my XML and Java for the Main Activity and the XML contains the mainFrame for my layout.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mTextMessage;

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.shareFrame:
                transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, new shareFragment()).commit();
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_share);
                return true;
            case R.id.settingsFrame:
                transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, new settingsFragment()).commit();
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_settings);
                return true;
            case R.id.helpFrame:
                transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, new helpFragment()).commit();
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_help);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, new shareFragment()).commit();
    }

}
```

Here is the Java for my shareFragment.java

```
public class shareFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public shareFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment shareFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static shareFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    shareFragment fragment = new shareFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_share, container, false);
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

And here is the XML

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/shareFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.swapdrop.swapdrop.shareFragment">

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: post your layout

Comment: Just for my MainActivity? I have 3 other fragments

Comment: whichever contains the mainFrame layout

Comment: Done, sorry it took a while

Comment: Can you post just one of your Fragments code?

Comment: Sure, I'll post my settings fragment Java and XML

Comment: @inner_class7 Just edited my original post to include Code

Comment: Is your Fragment from v4? you did not include the imports, but also it looks like you fragment contains absolutely nothing. Try just changing the background of the layout to some color so you can see it is showing when you do the transaction.

Comment: Yeah I tried this with a simple button but saw no change, when you press on different fragments from the navigation bar, they don't become selected is just what I'm trying to solve

Comment: And I'm not sure what you mean by v4

Comment: There is a support fragment and a regular Fragment. Which one are you extending, just include the list of imports in your ShareFragment

Comment: @inner_class7 Here is the list of imports from my shareFragment.java

Comment: import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your calling the empty Constructor.

Change:

```
transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, new shareFragment()).commit();
```

to

```
transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, shareFragment.newInstance("arg 1","arg 2")).commit();
```

Also, java convention is to upper case class names. shareFragment -> ShareFragment

Answer (score 1):

Try change your layout with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.swapdrop.swapdrop.MainActivity"
    android:background="#d3d3d3">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now `mainFrame` is the FrameLayout instead of the parent Layout

Comment: Tried this and it didn't change much, thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Sorry, still no difference

Answer (score 1):

Your root layout shouldn't be the "mainFrame". You should have a child ViewGroup to contain the fragment. Something like this:

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
        android:background="#d3d3d3" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try something like:

```
transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, shareFragment().newInstance("param1", " param2")).commit();
```

since the default constructor is not returning any Fragment().